# Must GCMIntentService always be in the base package?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my manifest, I have package as `com.business.project`, which is the base package of my app. From there I have other packages such as `com.business.project.activities` and `com.business.project.utils`. Anyway, I have a class `public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService` for android push notification. I would rather not have it in the base package, but when I move it push notification does not work. Is it a requirement for that class to always exist in the base package?

Comment: Check in manifest. In manifest specify proper package to receiver tag. It will  work fine even if GCMIntentService class is not in main package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that in any package you need, 
But make sure to define the correct path in  manifest as follows ,

```
 <service android:name="com.business.project.<util / activities >.GCMIntentService " />
```